Gitlab commit message is not displaying description
I have commit in Gitlab. The commit has title and description. While trying to fetch the commit message from Gitlab using regress operations, By default Gitlab is giving its own title. And if the commit description is lengthy, GitLab is ignoring it and only title being reflected once merged. I want the description also to be fetched. How can I implement it?

Please can you add the commands that you are currently using to try and extract the commit messages? I assume you are trying to extract information from a remote (online) Gitlab repo, rather than a local clone?

I'm editing it directly in web UI. Both online and in-house hosting of Gitlab reflect the same issue.

When you say "While trying to fetch the commit message from Gitlab using regress operations,", what exactly are you doing?

Fetching is not an issue actually, The template in Gitlab is  by default having a template. I want to tweak that template to display the detailed explanation too.

This gives all the template macros that you can use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/commit_templates.html. I'd suggest that you want to switch out %{title} and replace it with %{description}, although I'm not entirely sure that's what you are after.

@MattPitkin The docs you shared solved mu issue. tnx
